# iOS: Object equality when enumerating

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Say I have a `NSArray`, and each item is an `NSDictionary` with three keys keyA, keyB, and keyC - each referring to objects of unknown type `(id)`.

If I wanted to write a method that found the given element with those three keys i.e.

```
-(NSDictionary *) itemThatContainsKeys:(id)objectA and:(id)objectB and:(id)objectC
```

would I run into trouble by simply enumerating through and testing object equality via `if([i objectForKey:(keyA) isEqualTo:objectA]`) etc? I would be passing in the actual objects that were set in the dictionary initialization - ie not strings with the same value but different locations.

Is this bad practise?
Is there a better way to do this without creating a database?

Comment: If you are going to pass the same objects you have created, wouldn't `==` be more appropriate than `isEqualTo`?

Comment: I suppose? I'm still learning - and am not a computer scientist. Do you mind explaining the difference to me?

Comment: @Hippo `isEqualTo` probably implements `==` as one of their first checks anyways, so it's a moot point. Using `isEqualTo` gives you broader coverage

Comment: @iWasRobbed: I agree. However, `==` would still be appropriate if you wanted to restrict the kind of comparison being done.

Comment: @JoshDG: `==` compares the pointer values, while `isEqualTo` allows you to override the behavior in your classes to do a custom comparison using actual data in the object (useful when two objects created separately are "essentially" the same because they contain the same data).

Comment: By the way, a good discussion about equality: http://nshipster.com/equality

Answer (score 1):

You can override isEqual to stipulate the notion of equality for your type. The same rules apply as in other languages:

- If you provide an implementation of equals you should provide an implementation of 'hash'
- Objects that are 'equal' should have the same 'hash'
- Equals should be transitive -> if A equals B, and B  equals C, then C must equal A.
- Equals should be bi-directional -> if A equals B, then B must equal A.

This will ensure predictable behavior in classes like NSSet, that use hash for performance, falling back to equals on when there's a collision.

As Jason Whitehorn notes, Objective-C also has the convention of providing another isEqualToMyType method for convenience.

**AppCode, EqualsBuilder, Boiler-plate code**

It would be nice if there was something like Apache's 'EqualsBuilder' class, but in the meantime [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) does a fine job of implementing these methods for you.

Answer (score 0):

The isEqual: method compares object identity unless overwritten by a subclass. Depending on what class the target is, this May or may not be what you want. What I prefer is to use a more class specific comparison like isEqualToNumber: simply because of it's explicitness. But, isEqual should work depending on the target.

Other than that, and not knowing more specifics of what you're doing, it's hard to say if there is a better way to accomplish what you're after. But, here are my thoughts;

An array of a dictionary almost sounds like you might need a custom class to represent some construct in your app. Perhaps the dictionary could be replaced with a custom object on which you implement an isEqualToAnotherThing: method. This should simplify your logic.

Comment: There's no difference in the semantics of `isEqual:` and `isEqualTo<class>:`. While `NSObject` implements `isEqual:` to compare pointers, each Cocoa value class overides it to compare using value semantics.

Comment: Do you have some reference for this? Because I've seen no document that implies isEqual and (say) isEqualToNumber are the same. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:

Comment: `isEqualTo<class>` just does additional comparisons.  So it might start by checking `==` and `isKindOfClass` and if one of those fails, then it returns NO.  Then it might go deeper and check value comparisons like `does numberA == numberB`

Comment: I stand corrected. I see that Foundation classes do override isEqual. I'll edit.